# Implementing JMS Message Consumers

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb, jms, producer-consumer

I'm using **JMS** to send messages between a producer and multiple consumers. I already have the producer that send messages to a queue and now I want to implement multiple consumers that will receive the message according their **JMSXGroupID** parameter.

I want to implement those consumers using an **EJB** (not MDBs), that will launch a Consumer for each Queue Message.

But I'm having difficulties in found information about how to implement Message Consumers using EJBs and how to launch them (probably using **Threads**).

Can you give some lights about that, or tell me where can I find good information?

Comment: avoid using threads inside EJBs. Why not MDBs?

Comment: I've already implemented with MDBs. But after some hours working, new messages in the queue are not all being consumed... So I'm trying another implementation to find out if the same happens.

Comment: this is not supposed to happen. What EJB container and JMS implementation are you using?

Comment: Well, I'm using a QueueSender that sends messages to an HornetQueue (a LastValueQueue, more specifically). MDBs are processing those messages according the JMSXGroupID. I'm using EJB 3.0, HornetQ 2.2.14.Final, Jboss 5.1.0GA